Can I still find the data for GDP, PPP (constant 2011 international $) of all countries from world bank?
Can I still find the data for GDP, PPP (constant 2011 international $) of all countries from world bank?
On the world bank website https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.PP.KD  (Access 2024/10/9), only the data for GDP, PPP (constant 2021 international $) are available now.
However, I need the data for GDP, PPP (constant 2011 international $). Can I still find that in world bank website, or should I convert that by myself?

The World Bank hosts the data in 2011 prices on their World Integrated Trade Solution site.

Thanks for the answer. I notice that for Andorra, Faroe Islands, Greenland, and Syrian Arab Republic, GDP PPP (constant 2011 international $) is not available on the website from your link, but its GDP PPP (constant 2021 international $) is available on the website from my link. Can I find the data for the above territories, or is it reasonable to convert the data for the above territories from constant 2021 international $ to 2011 international $ with a universal conversion factor based on the data from the two databases?

You could rescale 2021 constant prices to fill missing data. I would attatch a footnote on any analysis stating this and cite the alternative data source.
